# MySQL entity and entity's aliases: How to remove UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, union

I have these tables in database:

- entities(id, name, deleted)
- entities_aliases(entity_id, alias_id)
- aliases(id, name)

This query are works fine, but slow due UNION, notice how entities.name swapped with aliases.name and moved to last column:

```
SELECT entities.id, entities.name, entities.deleted, NULL AS main_name
FROM entities
UNION
SELECT entities.id, aliases.name, entities.deleted, entities.name AS main_name
FROM entities
JOIN entities_aliases ON entities_aliases.entity_id = entities.id
JOIN aliases ON entities_aliases.alias_id = aliases.id
ORDER BY name
```

This swapping is very important for me, I can't remove it, but UNION will get slower and slower as database develops in width (more fields and links) and depth (more records). How I can get rid of UNION?

**Added:**
The output I need. For example, we have entity 1-AAA and his aliases 1-BBB and 2-CCC. The output should be:

- AAA
- BBB (AAA)
- CCC (AAA)

Comment: If you're sure `entities.name` is always distinct from `ANY (aliases.name)` for a given `entity_id`, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I would like to ask what is the output that you expect from this query that brings you to the idea of using union? can't say what proper query could be an alternative for this one though cause we don't really know what results you were expecting to achieve please explain further the logic of the results you want to have

Comment: can you put the structure of the tables to make testing here before to give you the answer? you can go here and create it too http://sqlfiddle.com/#

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it using LEFT JOINS and a few IFs:

```
SELECT e.id, IFNULL( a.name, e.name ) AS name, e.deleted, IF( a.name IS NULL, NULL, e.name ) AS main_name
FROM entities AS e
LEFT JOIN entities_aliases AS ea ON e.id = ea.entity_id
LEFT JOIN aliases AS a ON ea.alias_id = a.id;
```

If I understood what you wanted, you want "name" to be the alias name or the entity name if there's no alias (in this order), and main_name to be null when you don't have an alias, and the entity name when you do have an alias.
I hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you, alghimo, but I need e.name as separate result record also and LEFT JOIN doesn't give this. I need like this: AAA, BBB (AAA), CCC (AAA), where AAA - e.name and BBB, CCC is a.name.

Comment: Maybe I should add all entity names as alias names and leave it out with LEFT JOIN and compare it in view of MVC if $name == $main_name don't show main_name in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The following query simply uses UNION ALL instead of UNION:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT entities.id, entities.name, entities.deleted, NULL AS main_name
       FROM entities
      ) union all
      (SELECT entities.id, aliases.name, entities.deleted, entities.name AS main_name
       FROM entities e join
            entities_aliases ea
            ON ea.entity_id = e.id JOIN
            aliases a
            ON ea.alias_id = a.id
     )
    ) e
ORDER BY name
```

The UNION ALL removes the "distinct" process from the query.

Good formatting *which I subjectively define as the way that I do things) makes it easier for me to see the query.  Also:

1. Be sure that entities.entity_id is the primary key on entities.
2. Be sure that alias.id is the primary key on alias.

You are not doing any filtering, so a foreign key relationship on entity_aliases is optional.

Comment: Thank you! But do I need that additional SELECT * for ordering by? Seems it works perfect without it.

Comment: No, strictly speaking you can just do the union with the order by without the outer select.